# Nexus 5 boot loop after depleted battery shutdown

Tags: nexus-5, boot-loop, stock-android, twrp

Yesterday my phone turned off after the battery had depleted and now, after charging it, both the OS and TWRP are stuck when trying to boot (on boot animation and TWRP boot image respectively).

- I'm currently using an Android 6.0 stock image, and have been doing so since at least a year and a half.
- I haven't flashed/changed anything since the last time I flashed the stock image.
- The phone has turned off due to battery depletion before without any issues afterwards.
- I did noticed that battery was depleting faster than usual, I was sharing my 4G internet via tethering for a while, but I turned it off (and checked that it was off when I noticed the battery level) so that's why I thought it was weird.
- I can boot into the bootloader.

Flashing a new ROM would be less than ideal, so I would really appreciate any ideas/suggestions that can avoid it -- not that I'm wouldn't consider that solution, but I'd rather leave that as a last option.

Cheers!

EDIT:

Since I can access the bootloader I thought to try and flash a new Recovery. The recovery that is currently stuck trying to boot is `twrp-3.0.2-0-hammerhead`, through using `fastboot flash recovery` cmd I tried to flash a new image `twrp-3.1.0-0-hammerhead` (notice I'm upgrading `v3.0.2` to `v3.1.0`) now although the recovery still shows the old boot image for `v3.0.2` and takes a couple of minutes to boot, the system log shows this errors:

- `Failed to mount '/cache' (invalid argument)`
- `Failed to mount '/persist' (invalid argument)`
- Unable to mount storage

I followed this steps to flash: phone off, boot into bootloader, flash, reboot bootloader, reboot into recovery.